# How to target a checkbox by id and value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am running into issues targeting a checkbox by it's id (serviceType-checkbox) and value (0) but am running into issues. Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="serviceType-checkbox" name="serviceType[]" value="0" />
```

jQuery:

```
target = jQuery("#serviceType-checkbox[value='0']");
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: each checkbox should have a different id and be put into an html <fieldset>.  You want jQuery("#serviceType-checkbox");

Comment: Why is the `value` portion necessary? Targeting it by ID should be all the qualification you need to isolate this single checkbox.

Comment: Why do you need to include the value here?  You can just target by `id`.

Comment: To address the two comments above this one, perhaps the OP only wants to style that element if the value is 0.

Comment: What kind of error do you get ? Because if I reproduce your code in jsFiddle like [here] https://jsfiddle.net/mbexf33a/ it works

Comment: Thanks @laura. I checked again and it is indeed working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try this:

```
var target = jQuery("#serviceType-checkbox[value='0']");
target.click(function(event) {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery return its own object, If you want to return the selected object then you have to select its first index like:

```
  target = jQuery("#serviceType-checkbox[value='0']")[0];
```

You can check it jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s30nvmpn/